# How far does a PCB antenna need to be from a capacitive sensing touch button?

Tags: rf, antenna, interference, pcb-antenna, touch-panel

From my basic understanding, capacitive touch works by having a small voltage applied to a touch plane on a PCB, resulting in a uniform electrostatic field. When a conductor (human finger) touches the uncoated surface, a capacitor is dynamically formed and a touch is detected due to this change in the capacitance. Now, if I wanted to have an RF antenna (dipole) near a capacitive sensing plane, would there be any issue for either the antenna or the touch plane? If so, how far apart would they have to be to mitigate any major loss in efficiency?

Comment: I think at this point, it would be a good idea to start filling in your question with specifics. If not what your asking for is the stuff of research papers and electric field FEM solvers.

Comment: an ideal vertical antenna will have a NULL right above the vertical. Can you place the button there?

Comment: It  works differently by applying an AC voltage between sensing and reference plane at some frequency (kHz) such that the dielectric of the finger tip couples the signal from one to the other by capacitance. Not static. RF can be rejected by impedance dance control.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf I get it now. Unfortunately, no. They need to be parallel so to speak.